# Changing Base Path In PHP

Tags: php

I need to change the folder that "relative include paths" are based on.

I might currently be "in" this folder:
C:\ABC\XYZ\123\ZZZ

And in this case, the path "../../Source/SomeCode.php" would actually be in this folder:
C:\ABC\XYZ\Source

And realpath('.') would = 'C:\ABC\XYZ\123\ZZZ';

If however, realpath('.') were "C:\Some\Other\Folder"

Then in this case, the path "../../Source/SomeCode.php" would actually be in this folder:
C:\Some\Source

How do I change what folder is represented by '.' in realpath()?

Like this:

```
echo ('BEFORE = '.realpath('.')); // BEFORE = C:\ABC\XYZ\123\ZZZ
// Some PHP code here...
echo ('AFTER = '.realpath('.')); // AFTER = C:\Some\Other\Folder
```

How can I change the folder represented by '.', as seen by realpath()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `chdir()` does this.
For example:

```
echo ('BEFORE = '.realpath('.')); // BEFORE = C:\ABC\XYZ\123\ZZZ
chdir('C:/Some/Other/Folder');
echo ('AFTER = '.realpath('.')); // AFTER = C:\Some\Other\Folder
```

Comment: Don't use backslashes.  Use forward slashes.  It works on *all* operating systems.

Comment: Well, yes, but C:\ wouldn't, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It does matter, since it affects portability. Unless you have an absolute requirement to reference the drive letter, you should use Unix-style paths and let PHP translate them for you. That's why the functionality is there.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`chdir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Change your current working directory with `chdir()`

http://us.php.net/chdir